# Как правильно в css писать calc?

Tags: html, css

Не работает `calc((400px / 1920px) * 100%)`

Как правильно написать?

```css
div {
  max-width: calc((400px / 1920px) * 100%); /*? 20.83333333333333% */
  /*max-width: 20.83333333333333%;*/
  height: 50px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: какой результат ожидается?

Comment: 20.83333333333333%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у Вас фиксированные значения, то делите пиксели на число, а не на пиксели. Также и с процентами - [делите или умножайте на целое число или десятичную дробь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/calc()#%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81).

Здесь делим `px` на число и умножаем получившиеся пиксели снова на число - получаем размер в пикселях:

```css
div {
  max-width: calc((400px / 1920) * 100); /* 20.83333333333333px */
  /*max-width: 20.83333333333333%;*/
  height: 50px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

В этом варианте, вычисляем нужный коэффициент и умножаем на проценты - получаем размер в процентах:

```css
div {
  max-width: calc((400 / 1920) * 100%); /* 20.83333333333333% */
  /*max-width: 20.83333333333333%;*/
  height: 50px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```